# Count elements on click

Tags: jquery, class, click

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.filter_author_wrapper', function(event) {

            var filter_author_wrapper_selected = $('.f_a_w_selected');
            var selected_authors_num = filter_author_wrapper_selected.length;

            if ($(this).hasClass('f_a_w_selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('f_a_w_selected')
                    .queue(function() {
                        var filter_authors_selected = $('#filter_authors_selected');
                        filter_authors_selected.html(selected_authors_num + ' /');
                        $(this).dequeue();                      
                    });
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('f_a_w_selected')
                    .queue(function() {
                        var filter_authors_selected = $('#filter_authors_selected');
                        filter_authors_selected.html(selected_authors_num + ' /');
                        $(this).dequeue();                      
                    });
            }

        });
```

Every time I click on an element `.f_a_w_selected` class would be applied, or removed if it's already applied, AND count how many elements have this class.

The above code counts the elements that had the specific class BEFORE the click. How can I apply this class and count the elements with this class, by one click?

I hope this is understandable!

Comment: What do you mean by one click?  Isn't it doing everything in one click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay... sorry, but your code is a bit verbose, so let me rewrite it...

```
$(document).on('click', '.filter_author_wrapper', function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('f_a_w_selected');
  var num = $('.f_a_w_selected').length;
  $('#filter_authors_selected').html(num + ' /');
});
```

Also, `document` probably isn't the closest ancestor to your `.filter_author_wrapper`'s, so to get better performance out of delegated events, please attach your handler to the ***closest parent element present in the DOM at time of initialization***